# How could this looped animation be made in Blender?

Tags: animation

I was watching Six Major Paris, and noticed a looped animated background they use for shoutcasters' scene, and just wondered how it made using Blender?

The looped animation is here:
https://youtu.be/mX-N4aIBrXQ

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Blender

Comment: I think there is a plane, and some low-poly meshes that are changed by some shapekeys

Comment: sorry, i was meant to ask about how to build something like this in blender

Comment: If the link goes down, then the question will not make any sense. Please edit it to illustrate it with pictures and detailed explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... the way I would make an animation like that is to have a plane with an object poking through it. The object poking through it would then have a number of shape keys assigned to it and I'd slowly cycle from one shape to another over the course of the animation using the shape keys.